# Carregar dados extras pelo id recebido pelo array

Tags: php

Tenho uma página que recebe o ID(s) do(s) produto(s) que já estão salvos na tabela 'produtos' e que estão sendo adicionados via `$_POST` em um array que recebe esses dados(nome_produto, id_produto, valorunitario,quant_produto)

Na tabela de 'produtos' já estão salvos esses dados, como o id_produto, nome_produto,etc, e também outros dados como ipi, icms, cofins.

Estou recebendo via `$_POST` apenas alguns campos como o `ID`(s) do Produto(s) adicionado(s), preciso também consultar o RESTANTE dos dados VINCULADOS a esse(s) ID(s), que já estão salvo(s) na tabela 'produtos' (ex: ipi,icms,cofins).

RESUMINDO: Pegar também os outros campos da tabela produtos vinculado a cada `ID` adicionado via `$_POST` em forma de arrays (ex.: id_produto[] )

```
//POST em array que recebo

$valor_unitario = $_POST['valorunitario'];
$nome-produto= $_POST['nome_produto'];
$quant_produto = $_POST['quant_produto'];
$subtotal = $_POST['subtotal'];
$id_produto = $_POST['id_produto'];


//AQUI INSERE OS ARRAYS NO BANCO DE DADOS, RECEBE OS PRODUTOS ADICIONADOS VIA POST (AQUI QUERO SALVAR O RESTANTE DOS CAMPOS DO PRODUTO ATRAVÉS DO ID DELES.
$i=0;
$sql= "INSERT INTO `log_nfe_produtos` (`NOME_PRODUTO`, `VALOR_UNITARIO`, `QUANT_PRODUTO`, `SUBTOTAL`, `ID_EMPRESA`,`ID_NF`) VALUES ";

foreach($nome_produto as $p){

$sql=$sql."('$p','$valor_unitario[$i]','$quant_produto[$i]','$subtotal[$i]','1','$cod_pedido[$i]'),";

$i++;

}

$sqlFinal = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)-1);

$sqlFinal2 = $conn->prepare("$sqlFinal");

$sqlFinal2->execute();
```

Comment: Ok, irei comentar: sua pergunta não faz muito sentido. Tem como [edit] e tentar ser mais claro em seu texto?

Comment: Ok, alterei a pergunta, verifica se você tem condições de resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Então se deseja resgatar os valores do produto que foi enviado por post antes de realizar esse insert tem que fazer um select antes em sua base de dados pelo id do produto;

```
$dbi     = Conexao::singleton();
$query   = mysql_query("SELECT IPI,ICMS,CONFINS FROM PRODUTOS WHERE ID_PRODUTO =".$id_produto,$dbi);
$valores = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Agora para utilizar os valores coletados no banco com o id do produto basta fazer assim:
    $valores['IPI'];
    $valores['ICMS'];
    $valores['CONFINS'];

Exemplo não utiliza a classe mysqli mas pode seguir essa documentação de como trabalhar com essa classe.

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php

Espero que ajude ao entendimento.

Alterando conforme solicitado em comentário :

```
$dbi            = Conexao::singleton();
$listaProdutos  = Array(0,1,32,58,10);
for($i=0;$i<count($listaProdutos);$i++){
   $query   = mysql_query("SELECT IPI,ICMS,CONFINS FROM PRODUTOS WHERE 
   ID_PRODUTO =".$listaProdutos[$i],$dbi);
   $valores = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC);
   // Aqui pode entrar seu insert para notas fiscais utilizando os valores 
   //coletados da tabela produtos e do POST
}
```

> Expicação utilizei um loop FOR para ler um array com id de produtos a cada >incremento do laço. Vamos lendo uma posição nova do array e consultando no >banco de dados os valores referentes ao produto que são  IPI, ICMS e COFINS.

Array é nada mais que uma lista:

> $listaProdutos = Array(0,1,32,58,10);
>
> $listaProdutos[0] = 0; 
>   $listaProdutos[1] = 1;
>   $listaProdutos[2] = 32;
>   $listaProdutos[3] = 58;
>   $listaProdutos[4] = 10;

Existe uma outra solução para o que acho que quer fazer. Se quer inserir o IPI , ICMS e COFINS na tabela de notas fiscais poderia fazer esse select dentro do própio insert é mais trabalhoso e demorado mas no entanto consome muito menos recurso da maquina.

Pode apenas fazer isso :

```
 INSERT INTO log_nfe_produtos (`NOME_PRODUTO`, `VALOR_UNITARIO`, `QUANT_PRODUTO`, `SUBTOTAL`, `ID_EMPRESA`,`ID_NF`,'IPI','ICMS','COFINS')
 SELECT '$valor_unitario[$i]','$quant_produto[$i]','$subtotal[$i]','1','$cod_pedido[$i]', IPI,ICMS,COFINS FROM PRODUTOS WHERE ID_PRODUTO =".$id_produto;
```

Comment: Esse exemplo que você informou, funciona se no array tiver mais que 1 produto (2,3,4,5 produtos,etc) ?

Comment: Como assim? Especifique melhor que posto ali a resposta! Esse exemplo pega o valor de um produto pelo id dele no banco de dados para carregar IPI,CONFINS e ICMS. Mas se forem vários produtos irmão, você pode montar isso dentro de loop FOR .

Comment: Sim, como é array e recebe ID(s) (o (s) significa que poderia ser ou não vários ID(s) ), achei que entenderia que seria vários produtos...A FUNÇÃO QUE JÁ TENHO POSTADA JÁ PEGA OS PRODUTOS ENVIADOS PELO ARRAY E SALVA (mas gostaria que antes de efetuar esse insert ele carregasse os dados restantes de cada produto)

Comment: "Existe uma outra solução para o que acho que quer fazer. Se quer inserir o IPI , ICMS e COFINS na tabela de notas fiscais poderia fazer esse select dentro do própio insert é mais trabalhoso e demorado mas no entanto consome muito menos recurso da maquina." ; Era isso que eu gostaria de fazer!